# Cache image as base64 then convert back to image

Tags: dart, flutter

So I'm trying to cache an image if an upload fails, due to the current limitations of flutter I think I will have to save it to shared preferences as a base64 file, then get it from shared preferences, convert it back to an image then upload that to firebase storage. My current code looks like so:

```
void saveImageToCache(File image) async {
  List<int> imageBytes = image.readAsBytesSync();
  String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes); //convert image ready to be cached as a string

  var cachedImageName = "image $fileName";
  instance.setString(cachedImageName, base64Image); // set image name in shared preferences

  var retrievedImage = instance.getString(cachedImageName);// once a connection has been established again, get the image file from the cache and send it to firebase storage as an image
  storageReference.putData(retrievedImage, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'base64'));

  var prefix = "data:image/png;base64,";
  var bStr = retrievedImage.substring(prefix.length);
  var bs = Base64Codec.codec.decodeString(bStr);
  var file = new File("image.png");
  file.writeAsBytesSync(bs.codeUnits);
  uploadTask = storageReference.child(fileName).putFile(file, const StorageMetadata(contentLanguage: "en"));

}
```

This is failing for me at `var bStr = retrievedImage.substring(prefix.length);` with error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List' where` and im still not sure if im doing the right thing.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Seems like recievedImage is not of type string. Ii is rather of type Uint8List. Therefore the substring method fails, because it is not called on a string. Why do you even need to convert sth. back to base64 in the first place? Can't you just use the string base64Image for storage?

Comment: Thanks for replying, ive shortened my code for the sake of the question, but its what will happen if there is no internet connection when uploading an image from the camera, so cache the image so it can be uploaded when there is a connection

Comment: check this plugin, maybe code inside can help

Comment: think you forgot to link @Tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend storing binary files to shared preferences. Especially since you're building an image cache.

I'd just store them to a file.

```
  Future<File> saveFile(File toBeSaved) async {
    final filePath = '${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/image_cache/image.jpg';
    File(filePath)
      ..createSync(recursive: true)
      ..writeAsBytes(toBeSaved.readAsBytesSync());
   }
```

This uses `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` from the [path provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) package.

Comment: This is great thank you so much. How do I get the contents of this directory to upload when there is a connection?

Comment: Have a look at the [`Directory`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Directory-class.html) docs.

Comment: ok thank you, when i run your code above i keep getting `Error saving file to shared preferences, error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path`

Comment: Error saving file to shared preferences?

Comment: @Wazza You need to make sure the folder `image_cache` already exists. Answer updated.